# Has there been any improvement in .Net TCP/IP library?

Tags: .net, performance, tcp

Sometimes back I had to work on plain TCP/IP client-server application using just .Net framework 2.0. I found that .net 2.0 socket library was quite inefficient and used to take lot of memory and processing cycles we then switched over to C++ and it worked very well.

**I want to check if there's been any improvements for TCP/IP library in .Net 3.0 or above.** What is your experience in case if you have used .Net TCP/IP library for both .Net 2.0 and .net frameworks after 2.0 ?

Comment: This sounds strange, the .NET socket library is a rather small layer on top of the native sockets - we're pushing substantial amount of data through .NET and never had any issues with memory or processor bottlenecks.(.NET 2 and 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

I've not had any problems with the basic `Socket` class; as "nos" pointed out, it's just a really thin layer over the WinSock API.

They did add the whole `*Async` / `SocketAsyncEventArgs` - based API to `Socket` in .NET 2.0 SP1 (note that this should *not* be confused with the Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern, which uses `*Async`, `*Completed`, and `*AsyncEventArgs` naming conventions). The point of this API is to reduce stress on the GC by reusing native `OVERLAPPED` structures instead of having to allocate and GC them on every read and write.

I have not actually used the `*Async` API; I use the `Begin*`/`End*` API and have not had any performance issues of note. To my knowledge, no changes were introduced to the `Socket` class since 2.0 SP1.